# Use ENV variable within regex

Tags: apache, validation, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use some created local variables as part of the validations required by the regular expression. My code so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*redirect=(.*?)(?:&.*|$)
RewriteRule .* - [E=REDIRECT:%1]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/(.*?)(?:\/-*|\s)
RewriteRule .* - [E=TEST_IDEA:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT} =%{ENV:TEST_IDEA} ###This doesn't work as '=' takes %{ENV:TEST_IDEA} lexicographically.
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

As a tangential point, I'm trying to validate that both the referer and the GET method for a URL share something in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ap_expr` comparisons](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/expr) if you pass in the first argument to `RewriteCond` as literal `expr`:

```
RewriteCond expr "%{ENV:REDIRECT} = %{ENV:TEST_IDEA}"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```